# Is there a simple way to install L2PT VPN in Ubuntu 14.04 x64?

Tags: 14.04, vpn

I apple Ubuntu 14.04 x64 hsoting at the https://www.vultr.com/

I have installed PPTP VPN using the following code, it's OK!

```
wget https://raw.github.com/viljoviitanen/setup-simple-pptp-vpn/master/setup.sh
sudo sh setup.sh
```

I hope to install L2PT VPN in Ubuntu 14.04 x64, how can I do?

BTW, I'm a beginner of Ubuntu, I hope there is a simple script just like the above code to do that.

And more: https://github.com/philplckthun/setup-simple-ipsec-l2tp-vpn don't work

https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn don't work too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of the VPN setup scripts at https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn

What error(s) did you encounter? Please follow the instructions for Ubuntu and Debian under the "Installation" section of the repo's home page.

**Added on 01/10/2016:**
If you get Error 809 when connecting to an IPsec/L2TP VPN server in Windows, try making a one-time registry change to enable connections to VPN servers behind NAT. Here is the registry key to add:

```
For Windows XP:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\IPSec

RegValue: AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule

Type: DWORD

Data Value: 2


For Windows Vista, 7, 8, 10, and 2008 Server:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PolicyAgent 

RegValue: AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule

Type: DWORD

Data Value: 2
```

You must **reboot** the computer after creating this registry key.

Sources:
https://documentation.meraki.com/MX-Z/Client_VPN/Troubleshooting_Client_VPN#Windows_Error_809
Also see Microsoft KB: support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/926179

Comment: Thanks!

It seems that everything is OK when I install L2TP using the instructions for Ubuntu and Debian under the "Installation" section of the repo's home page.
You can see the image https://www.dropbox.com/s/j36q5mml1bs2qi5/l2tp.zip?dl=0

but I get the Error 809 in Windows 7 when I try to connect using my L2TP account.

Comment: BTW, I test your script in my fresh Ubuntu 14.04 x64 hosting

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: After I write the following content to windows 7 registry, it's Ok

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\RasMan\Parameters]
"ProhibitIpSec"=dword:00000000


Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PolicyAgent]
"AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule"=dword:00000002

Comment: @HelloCW I have updated my answer to add the new information. By the way, only the `AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule` registry key is required.

Comment: Tanks! but there are some problems with your script. My  shadowsocks server don't work after install you script.

Comment: And more, my office PC can't connect to L2TP , I have added the key AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule, I get the error 809

Comment: BTW, In CentOS 6 , I can use the following code to create L2TP and connect correctly.

cd /root
wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teddysun/across/master/l2tp_ubuntu.sh
chmod +x l2tp_ubuntu.sh
./l2tp_ubuntu.sh

Comment: @HelloCW Thanks for the link. Please edit your IPTables rules at `/etc/iptables.rules`, and open the ports required for shadowsocks. Then run `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules`. Did you reboot your office PC after adding the registry key? Please double check that you added it correctly.

Comment: And more, did you mean that your L2Tp script  modify IPTables, it makes that shadowsocks disable? If so, I think that maybe you need to modify your script because many users is beginner of Linux

Comment: @HelloCW Yes it does modify IPTables. Thanks for pointing that out! Actually the port for shadowsocks is configurable and may be different for everyone. If you need to open additional ports in IPTables (e.g. for shadowsocks), just edit the `iptables.rules` file as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks! but I think your script should not to cause other server down, you know that many beginner such as me can't understand what error cause shadowsocks server down, and don't know how to fix errors. So I think maybe you should  to modify your script. And more I'm very strange that shadowsocks use customize port which hardly conflict with other server, why do your script need to disable the port of shadowsocks?

Comment: @HelloCW Thanks for the feedback. The script is intended to be used on a freshly installed Linux system, and the IPTables rules are designed to better protect the server by whitelisting only the ports required for the VPN. If you need further help, feel free to leave a comment here!

Comment: Thanks! Will  shadowsocks be Ok if I install your script first, then install shadowsocks ?

Comment: @HelloCW Yes you can do that. However, after installing shadowsocks you must open iptables ports by running: `iptables -I INPUT 6 -p tcp --dport SERVER_PORT -j ACCEPT`, `iptables -I INPUT 6 -p udp --dport SERVER_PORT -j ACCEPT`, `iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules`. Replace both SERVER_PORT above with the port you configured for shadowsocks. Ref: https://shadowsocks.org/en/config/quick-guide.html